# importing opencv moduls

Tags: python, opencv

I have a simple code as mentioned below:

```
import cv
from opencv.cv import *
from opencv.highgui import *

img = cv.LoadImage("test.jpg")
cap = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
while cv.WaitKey(1) != 10:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(cap)
    cv.ShowImage("cam view", img)
cascade = cv.LoadHaarClassifierCascade('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml', cv.Size(1,1))
```

But I faced to this error:

```
# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LoadImage'
```

when I change the code to below:

```
import cv
#from opencv.cv import *
#from opencv.highgui import *

img = cv.LoadImage("test.jpg")
cap = cv.CreateCameraCapture(0)
while cv.WaitKey(1) != 10:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(cap)
    cv.ShowImage("cam view", img)
cascade = cv.LoadHaarClassifierCascade('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml', cv.Size(1,1))
```

now the first error got solve and another error raise.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LoadHaarClassifierCascade'
```

I need both of the modules but it seems that they have conflict to gether.

Now what I have to do?

Comment: Can you please specify which classes are contained in which module?

Comment: You aren't using any of the stuff you've imported in lines 2 and 3.  And as far as I understand how python works, it is impossible for commenting out those lines to solve your `AttributeError` in the first case (It's either in `cv` module or it's not, and importing more stuff into the global namespace is not going to change that)

Comment: from the error message you can identify that the last line of code need to this module importing!!!

Comment: @Amin please provide a link to the opencv framework you are using, so that we can have a look at the package structure etc.

Answer (score 5):

In OpenCV to load a haar classifier (in the python interface anyway) you just use cv.Load.

```
import cv
cascade = cv.Load('haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')
```

See the examples [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/objdetect_cascade_classification.html?highlight=load).

Also, the samples that come with the OpenCV source are really good (in `OpenCV-2.xx/samples/python`).

Answer (score 1):

How do you access the stuff you've imported?

```
# imports the cv module, all stuff contained in it and
# the module itself is now accessible via: cv.classname, cv.functionname
# where classname, functionname is the name of the class/function which
# the cv module provides..
import cv

# imports everything contained in the opencv.cv module
# after this import it is available via it's classname, functionname, etc.
# Attention: without prefix!!
from opencv.cv import *

# @see opencv.cv import 
from opencv.highgui import *
```

@see [python modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) for more details about modules and imports in python.

If you can provide which classes are contained in which module I could add a specific solution for your problem.

Comment: I think this question is more related to how to import OpenCV libraries properly, than import in Python in general

Comment: python opencv has some library that are with different syntax.